# Check if 2 columns exists in another 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have 2 sheets that both contain names and birth dates. I want to know if the combination of a name and a birth date in the first sheet exists as a combination of a name and a birth date in the second sheet.

I have seen in another post how to do it for one column comparisons. I tried this for the name and it works but I will have problem with people having the same name but different birth date.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(<cell in col A>,<column B>, 0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(<NameRange>,<NAME>,<BirthDayRange>,<BirthDay>)>0
```

Comment: Wont that cause problem if another person has the same birthday?

Comment: Only if that person has the same name.

Comment: COUNTIFS is an AND function.  Both criteria must return true for it to be counted.